# Train a pyg model with edge features only, no node level feature vector

Tags: python, vector, dataset, pytorch-geometric

With a dataset containing only edge features. This graph has nodes with no X features. This dataset is a set of edges about a network and its network flow. Ex: ip-address1, ip-address2 are the source & target nodes ... `the edge_attr`

To build a model in pytorch geometric (pyg) how do I pass the x (features) to the Data object?

Here is what I do now, but is not working:

```
X = np.zeros(shape=(len(node_indices),0))
x = torch.tensor(X, dtype=torch.double)
...
data = Data(x=x, edge_index=edge_index, edge_attr=edge_attr, y=y)
```

print data:
`Data(x=[1784, 0], edge_index=[2, 1087823], edge_attr=[1087823, 6], y=[1087823, 1])`

P.S. [A similar question is in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77258901/can-we-use-gnn-on-graphs-with-only-edge-features)

Answer (score 2):

A straightforward way to deal with graphs without node features is to give all the nodes the same feature, as shown in the following code. Here I suggest using `torch.ones` instead of `torch.zeros` as in some GNNs the message is multiplied with node embeddings.

```
X = torch.ones(size=(len(node_indices),1))
...
data = Data(x=X, edge_index=edge_index, edge_attr=edge_attr, y=y)
```

You also can create some node features based on the graph information, for example, using the Positional Encoding methods. In pytorch geometric, you can directly apply these methods by using transforms `AddLaplacianEigenvectorPE` and `AddRandomWalkPE`.

Comment: Looks like all we need to do is drop the `shape=` part, see [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.ones.html). 
I'll look the PEs mentioned, those are new to me.

Comment: Thanks I have updated the code and fixed the problem.